# Conditional BREAD in Laravel / Voyager

Tags: laravel, voyager

Is there a way to apply certain conditions to the list of records displayed by Voyager's BREAD? For example, only display records where a certain column is blank (i.e. `WHERE 'col_name' IS NULL`)?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE (17/12/18):**

---

You can override the controller and add the where clause. For example, if you need to override "Posts" list, then you should:

1. Make a custom PostController: `php artisan make:controller PostController`
2. Extend it from Voyager BREAD controller: `class PostController extends \TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\VoyagerBaseController`
3. Import Voyager's Facade: `use TCG\Voyager\Facades\Voyager;`
4. Copy the whole index function from VoyagerBaseController. You can find it in `\vendor\tcg\Voyager\Http\Controllers\VoyagerBaseController`
5. Override it to add any logic or filter you need, for example:

`$dataType = Voyager::model('DataType')
     ->where('slug', '=', $slug)
     ->where('col_name', '=', NULL)
     ->first();`

You can also set `$orderBy = 'col_name'` and `$sortOrder = 'asc'/'desc'` custom values in the same function. [Here](https://docs.laravelvoyager.com/customization/overriding-files) Voyager's docs.

**OLD:**

---

Yes, there is. You need to edit the view and apply a condition filter. [Here](https://docs.laravelvoyager.com/customization/overriding-files) is explained how to override views (and controllers if you want to filter it before sending the data to the view).

Comment: @SimplyGed I just edited it to answer the question. Ty.

Answer (score 3):

Just define a Scope in your model:

```
public function scopeMyScope($query)
{
    return $query->where('col_name', null);
}
```

then go to Bread Form and select it form Scope drop down :)